# new object data is not updated in realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

parsing Json data using Alamofire stored into the realm and showed into the table working fine. when am adding to multiple object to realm application is crashing

Json :

```
{ 
"worldpopulation": 
    [
         {
         "rank":1,"country":"China",
         "population":"1,354,040,000",
         "flag":"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/china.png"
         }, 

         {
         "rank":2,"country":"India",
         "population":"1,210,193,422",
         "flag":"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/india.png"
         }, 

         {
         "rank":3,"country":"United States",
         "population":"315,761,000",
         "flag":"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/unitedstates.png"
         }, 

         {
         "rank":4,"country":"Indonesia",
         "population":"237,641,326",
         "flag":"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/indonesia.png"
         }, 
         ] 
}
```

First time am showing **country name** only in table view
model Class

```
class Item : Object
{
    @objc dynamic var name = ""

}
```

next I can add the population to the table view when I added to next object the class after that its not working

```
class Item : Object
{
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var population = ""

}
```

this is the code update and showing data

```
var realm: Realm!
     var objectsArray: Results<Item> {
        get {
            return realm.objects(Item.self)
        }
    }
```

parsing data

```
func jsonparsing()
    {
        let url = URL(string:"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/jsonparsetutorial.txt")

        realm = try! Realm()

        Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
            .responseJSON(completionHandler: {
                response in
                let res = response.result.value as! [String:Any]
                let arrayvalue = res["worldpopulation"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                for imagearray in arrayvalue
                {
                    let item = Item()
                    try! self.realm.write {
                        item.name = imagearray["country"] as! String
                       item.population =  imagearray["population"] as! String
                        self.realm.add(item)
                        }
                    self.reloaddata()
                }
             }).resume()

    }
```

how to update multiple object to the realm, show into the table view

Comment: do you need update object after parse ?? please add more info

Comment: Please show us the error.  Also, what's the thread the Alamofire.request()'s completionHandler is called on? If not the main thread, you're going to need to jump to main thread within your completionHandler.

Comment: @Smartcat Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: ''Item' does not have a primary key and can not be updated' this is the error am getting

Comment: @a.masri I want update after the parsing, am getting Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: ''Item' does not have a primary key and can not be updated' this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adds or updates an existing object into the Realm.
Only pass true to update if the object has a primary key. If no object exists in the Realm with the same primary key value, the object is inserted. Otherwise, the existing object is updated with any changed values.

you should use

> self.realm.add(item, update: .all) // to update all properties with not diff calculated

OR

> self.realm.add(item, update: .modified) // to update only properties that were changed

By default the usage of

> self.realm.add(item)

Is equivalent to using:

> self.realm.add(item, update: .error)

and you should add primary key to your object

Comment: I will add the primary key after that am getting this error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: ''Item' does not have a primary key and can not be updated'

Comment: thanks Bro Problem is resolved I can add primary key to my code its working fine

Answer (score 0):

You must provide primary key in your classes.

Info from realm docs https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#objects-with-primary-keys

> If your model class includes a primary key, you can have Realm
>   intelligently update or add objects based off of their primary key
>   values using Realm().add(_:update:).

```
// Creating a book with the same primary key as a previously saved book
let cheeseBook = Book()
cheeseBook.title = "Cheese recipes"
cheeseBook.price = 9000
cheeseBook.id = 1

// Updating book with id = 1
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(cheeseBook, update: true)
}
```

> If a Book object with a primary key value of ‘1’ already existed in
>   the database, then that object would simply be updated. If it did not
>   exist, then a completely new Book object would be created and added to
>   the database.

Comment: @objc dynamic var id = 0
    
    func primaryKey() -> Int {
        return id
    } I can add this code as primary key am calling in as in cell for row index as item.id =  imagearray["rank"] as! Int after that getting this error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: ''Item' does not have a primary key and can not be updated' this error

Comment: Be attentive - it’s must be fresh install after code changes.

Comment: thanks Problem is resolved I can add primary key to my code its working fine